# How can I train dlib shape predictor using a very large training set

Tags: python, computer-vision, face-recognition, dlib

I'm trying to use the python `dlib.train_shape_predictor` function to train using a very large set of images (~50,000).

I've created an xml file containing the necessary data, but it seems like train_shape_predictor loads all the referenced images into RAM before it starts training. This leads to the process getting terminated because it uses over 100gb of RAM. Even trimming down the data set uses over 20gb (machine only has 16gb physical memory).

Is there some way to get train_shape_predictor to load images on demand, instead of all at once?

I'm using python 3.7.2 and dlib 19.16.0 installed via pip on macOS.

Answer (score 0):

I posted this as an issue on the dlib github and got this response from the author:

> It's not reasonable to change the code to cycle back and forth between disk and ram like that. It will make training very slow. You should instead buy more RAM, or use smaller images.

As designed, large training sets need tons of RAM.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://medium.com/@Petuum/a-solution-to-the-memory-limit-challenge-in-big-data-machine-learning-49783a72088b

Comment: Or set this param to 0

```upsample_limit
train_simple_object_detector() will upsample images if needed no more than upsample_limit times. Value 0 will forbid trainer to upsample any images. If trainer is unable to fit all boxes with required upsample_limit, exception will be thrown. Higher values of upsample_limit exponentially increases memory requirements. Values higher than 2 (default) are not recommended.```

Comment: @thachnb Thanks, but it looks like upsample_limit is only an option for train_simple_object_detector, not train_shape_predictor. In my situation scaling the images in the training set was pretty quick and easy. It reduced memory requirements by about 70% and I still got good results from training.

Comment: 70% is impressive number! How about before/after image size?

Comment: @thachnb I scaled all images that had width or height > 1024 down to 1024 using PIL's thumbnail method (then scaled the landmark coords in the xml). A lot of the images were at least twice that size. Since my application is looking for facial landmarks in 720p video, it doesn't seem to have negatively effected accuracy.