# Is there a way to reduce the ram usage when training with "dlib.train_simple_object_detector"?

Tags: object-detection, dlib

I've been trying to use "dlib.train_simple_object_detector" to make a detector to detect pedestrians. After a few hours of making rectangles in imglab I made the Inria person dataset consisting of about 600 into an xml file. But when I try to train on this data I get "MemoryError: bad allocation" I have 16GB ram but I guess that's not enough here.

So I reduce the amount of training images and find that it onlys starts working when there are about 100 images. 
When I try this detector on test images the detection rate is pretty bad so I would really like to train on all the images or atleast on more of them than 100.

So my questions are:

Is there a way to reduce the ram usage when training with "dlib.train_simple_object_detector"?

Is there an already trained .svm file somewhere that is trained for pedestrian detection that I can use insead?

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: did you see my [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54155910/how-can-i-train-dlib-shape-predictor-using-a-very-large-training-set)? I had good results scaling the images in the training set. I also ended up doing my training in Google Compute Cloud because you can create machines with many vCPUs (for multi-threaded training) and tons of RAM.

Comment: Thanks but what's the difference between the shape predictor and the simple object detector?